# How to stream webcam feed on web page using react js component?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video-streaming, webcam

I am new to reactJS and trying to build a component.

I want to build a basic utility where I have a video component that shows live webcam feed and there would be a capture button, to capture and store a snap of the feed to disk. I want it to be in a single component ( video feed + capture button)

This code streams the feed in browser but I want it in a component,

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">

    </video>
</div>
<script>
 var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
}

function handleVideo(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}

function videoError(e) {}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine, but not it's not a component.

I tried following in reaact js but it's not working:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        var MyComponent = React.createClass({
            handleVideo: function(stream) {
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            },
            videoError: function() {

            },
            render: function() {

            var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");

            navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

            if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
                navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, this.handleVideo, this.videoError);
            }
                return <div>
                        <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">
                        </video>
                       </div>;
            }
        });
    React.render( <MyComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));
    </script>
    </body>
```

The error is in handleVideo()

**ReferenceError: video is not defined.**

My understanding of error is,

since the video tag is coming in later part(in return), it's trying to use before the definition in handleVideo function.
i am confused how to make this work.

Thank you!

Comment: I didn't include this in my answer, since it's not actually part of the answer, but it looks like from your code that you are putting your React code in-line with your HTML.  JSX is designed to be used in Javascript files, and while you *can* put it into your HTML, you'll probably have more success keeping your component code in a separate file.  Your IDE won't be confused by the two HTML-like syntaxes in the same file, it will be easier to use tools like Babel to convert your JSX in to browser-friendly JS, etc.

Comment: Thank you,
I plan to put the react code in another file but I thought I could get the cod running first and then build the further functionality with separate files.

i am just learning by using Youtube video tutorials and this is how I started, by enhancing code in same file. :)

Comment: IMPORTANT:  The function createObjectURL is deprecated for Google Chrome. Use this instead:   function handleVideo(stream) {
      video.srcObject=stream;
  }

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few things to understand about the way React components work.  Firstly according to the React [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render):

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify
>   component state, it returns the same result each time it's invoked,
>   and it does not directly interact with the browser.

You should move initializing your video element to an alternate lifecycle method like `componentDidMount` to ensure that it is only initialized once.

Secondly, you rarely need to interact with the DOM directly.  In this case we can use the component's internal state to manage the src attribute for the video stream, ensuring it only updates after the stream has initialized.

Here's an updated component that might work:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return { videoSrc: null }
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, this.handleVideo, this.videoError);
    }
  },
  handleVideo: function(stream) {
    // Update the state, triggering the component to re-render with the correct stream
    this.setState({ videoSrc: window.URL.createObjectURL(stream) });
  },
  videoError: function() {

  },
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <video src={this.state.videoSrc} autoPlay="true" />
    </div>;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @jordan,

Thank you for your reply, "componentDidMount" is something I was looking for. I agree that render function should be kept pure :)

I tried the code you have suggested here above. I don't see any error in console but the video component is missing from the page.

It's accessing the webcam, (the light is ON) but the video component is missing :(



Thoughts?

Comment: I added the `"id=videoElement"` and the video component came back. Now it also has the src, but somehow, the box is empty. Lol

Comment: Did you see any errors in the debug console?  See my edited answer for a version that i've tested works.  You need to make sure the `videoError` function is still there.  Also `autoplay` becomes `autoPlay`

Comment: Jordan Burnett, I love you :P

autoplay to autoPlay made the feed go live :) 

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Some of the code posted in the answer has been deprecated and may no longer work in all browsers.
I have created a new React application which uses the latest syntax. 
It is very simple and straightforward. I hope it helps someone :)

```
class AppStreamCam extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.streamCamVideo= this.streamCamVideo.bind(this)
  }
  streamCamVideo() {
    var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } };
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(function(mediaStream) {
        var video = document.querySelector("video");

        video.srcObject = mediaStream;
        video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
          video.play();
        };
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
      }); // always check for errors at the end.
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="container">
          <video autoPlay={true} id="videoElement" controls></video>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <button onClick={this.streamCamVideo}>Start streaming</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's my Medium article about it :
  [How to create a React application to stream your webcam | Basic, Beginner](https://medium.com/@a.g.stranger/how-to-create-a-react-application-to-stream-your-webcam-basic-beginner-66c792993622)

If it helped don't forget to clap :)

Finally, here's the github repo of the working example : 
[Basic-WebCam-Streamer](https://github.com/AGSTRANGER/Basic-WebCam-Streamer)

Comment: Hi @Ahmed the github link is broken, Have you changed the repository name? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `handleVideo` method references `video`, but you don't define that variable anywhere `handleVideo` can see it.  Instead, you define it in `render`:

```
var video = document.querySelector("#videoElement");
```

So there's your first problem, but it's not your real problem.  Your real problem is that in React-land you want to avoid `document.anything` (`getElementById`, `getByTagAndClassName`, `querySelector`, etc.).  This is because React uses a virtual DOM, and if you aren't careful when you reference actual DOM elements those references can quickly go bad (as the virtual DOM replaces the actual DOM after a `render`).

The solution is to use React's own alternative technique: `refs`.  They're easier to explain by example, so here's your code fixed using `refs`:

```
handleVideo: function(stream) {
    // KEY CHANGE #1
    this.refs.video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
},
render: function() {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, this.handleVideo, this.videoError);
    }
    return <div>
        {{/* KEY CHANGE #2 */}}
        <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement" ref="video">
        </video>
    </div>;
```

In other words, if you add a `ref="something"` attribute to any element you return in your `render` function, you can reference that element anywhere else in your (React) code by referring to `this.refs.something`.

There's also other ways to use `refs` (eg. you can pass a function),  but that's outside the scope of this question, so I'd just recommend you read up on the React docs for `refs`:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

**EDIT**

As Jordan Burnett's answer highlighted, there are other important differences between React and normal JS DOM work.  Again, explaining all of them would be outside the scope of this question, but I strongly encourage you to read:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

to learn the appropriate methods to override to do DOM-interaction work (eg. binding event handlers on non-React components).

Comment: Thank you @machineghost for your reply. I will go through the docs you have mentioned above. I am sure it will help me.

Comment: For now, I have made changes you suggested to use "ref"

Now, the error message from console is gone, but I don't see the feed in my browser. it's just an empty box. However, the webcam's light is on.

Thoughts?

Comment: It sounds like maybe the video's `src` isn't getting set (I think a `<video>` without a `src` will look like an empty box).  This probably has something to do with `navigator.getUserMedia` not calling `handleVideo`, but I'm not familiar with how `navigator.getUserMedia` works (it's a deprecated API).  If I were you I would throw a `console.log` or `debugger` in `handleVideo` to see if it is being called.  If it is, check that `this.refs.video` exists and that `window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)` is returning what you expect.  If it isn't being called ... well there's your problem :)

Comment: Well, handleVideo is being called. 

`inside handleVideo blob:null/ffdeec81-e718-1244-8ba8-02500ab37d1c`(it's the value of window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)) `blob:null/c75a5290-cdde-1e4d-859c-6eea07aa7b22` (this is this.refs.video.src) 

The values are there, and I used "inspect element"; the SRC attribute is just missing from video tag.

Comment: I used console.log to see these values. it's working fine. but the video tag in html has only one attribute other than id, `data-reactid=.0.0`

Comment: It seems `handleVideo` isn't being called.  This is most likely a (separate) issue with timing.  Inside your React `render` method you build the "virtual DOM", not the real one.  It's only after the render occurs that the virtual DOM becomes the real DOM.  Because of this, you should also move your `navigator.getUserMedia` code out of `render` and in to `componentDidMount` (happens after first `render`) and/or `componentDidUpdate` (happens after every other `render`) methods (see the second link in my answer for more about them).

Answer (score 2):

This is AG_HIHI's solution written as functional component. I removed the start button, instead start right away once mouted. Place the AppStreamCam component in you parant react component and it shows your webcam feed. Worked like a charm for me.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'

const AppStreamCam = () => {

  const streamCamVideo = () => {
  var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } };
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(function(mediaStream) {
      var video = document.querySelector("video");

      video.srcObject = mediaStream;
      video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
        video.play();
      };
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
    }); // always check for errors at the end.
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    streamCamVideo()
  },[])

  return (
    <div>
        <video autoPlay={true} id="videoElement" ></video>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AppStreamCam
```

Comment: This worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **react-webcam**. follow the link below, it already has a "getScreenshot" function which returns the base64 encoded picture of the current frame from the webcam.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam

```
const WebcamCapture = () => {
  const webcamRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [imgSrc, setimgSrc] = React.useState(null);

  const capture = React.useCallback(
    () => {
      const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot();
      setimgSrc(imageSrc);

    },
    [webcamRef,setimgSrc]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Webcam
        audio={false}
        height={720}
        ref={webcamRef}
        screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
        width={1280}
      />
      <button onClick={capture}>Capture photo</button>
      {imgSrc && (<img src = {imgSrc}/>) }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Happy to help!